# Name of this quiver type

Tags: gear, archery, terminology

I noticed a few archers who have a different kind of quiver (different from a back-, bow- or side-quiver). It's kind of a pocket where the arrows are literally "plugged in". Just like in a bow-quiver for example. Yeah..., it's kind of a bow-quiver brought in the form of a pocket to wear on the belt.

Is there a name for this kind of quiver?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would, quite simply, be a pocket quiver.